# In order to play basketball, $10$ players divide themselves into two $5$ person teams. How many different divisions are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

In order to play basketball, $10$ players divide themselves into two $5$ person teams. How many different divisions are possible?

The answer isn’t $252$. I thought solving it would just be $\frac{10!}{5!5!}$.

Comment: The answer isn’t 252. I thought solving it would just be 10!/(5!5!)

Comment: What is the answer? 126? Since it doesn't matter which team is "team 1"

Answer (score 2):

Let's arbitrarily number the players from $1$ through $10$.  Player $1$ has $4$ teammates.  There are $\binom{9}{5}$ ways to choose those $4$ teammates and each of those choices gives a different way of dividing the players into teams, so the number of ways to divide the players is $126$.